# Let, $\alpha$ be the $13$'th root of unity, and we let $K = Q(\alpha)$, find a subfield $L$ of $K$ such that $[L:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

We know that, $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 12$. Let, $p(x) = x^{12} + x^{11} + x^{10} + \dots + x^2 + x + 1.$ We know that, $p(\alpha) = 0$. Let, $\beta = \alpha^{12} + \alpha^{11} + \alpha^{10} + \dots + \alpha^{4}$. We define, $q(x) = x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1 + \beta$. We have that, $q(\alpha) = 0$; hence,
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\beta)] = 3,$$
which implies by tower law of fields, $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$. So, $L = \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

Does my proof look correct? Any issues? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you know that $q$ is minimal over $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$?

Comment: You only know that the degree is _at_ _most_ $3$. In fact, I'd wager that it's $1$. :)

Comment: Gauss handled this using his theory of periods. For a prime $p$ if $g\mid p-1$ and $f\mid g$ then a period of $f$ terms is a root of polynomial of degree $g/f$ with coefficients being rational expressions of a period of $g$ terms. Here we can choose $g=12,f=3$ for $p=13$ and if $\beta$ is a period of 3 terms then $L=\mathbb {Q} (\beta) $ is of degree $4$ over rationals.

Comment: Since $2$ is a primitive root of $13$ a period of $3$ terms is given by $\beta=\alpha^{2^0}+\alpha ^{2^4}+\alpha^{2^8}$ which is same as $\beta=\alpha+\alpha^3+\alpha^9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that $q$ is minimal, which could be not an easy work. Another approach is, from the Fundamental theorem of Galois theory, find $Fix(f_3) $ because $<f_3>$ is a subgroup of order 3, it implies that $Fix(<f_3>) |\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $4$. Where $f_3$ is the automorphism such as $f_3(\alpha)=\alpha^3$

Comment: Shouldn't the automorphism map $\alpha$ to $\alpha^3$?

Comment: Oh Yes! Thank you